# JQuery: How to filter out "a" elements of an html string?

Tags: jquery

So, I have an HTML string that looks just like this:

```
<div>
<div class="venue-tooltip">
    Filling station
    <div>
        <a class="manage-venue-details" rel="venue-id-10" href="javascript:void(0);">Add filling station info</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to get all the contents without the "a" element, so basically to have something like this:

```
<div>
<div class="venue-tooltip">
    Filling station
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The HTML is loaded in a js string and I have tried those variants:

```
$(':not(a)', myHtmlString);
$(myHtmlString).not('a');
```

Both of them return unfiltered HTML. Any ideas?

My jQuery version is 1.6.1 and I test the above with Firefox 6

Comment: see my answer.. I updated my answer. had deleted it while editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use DOM manipulation functions to change a string. Try using regular expresions:

```
code.replace(/<a( |>).*?<\/a>/gi,"");
```

It's more efficient than convert string in DOM, manipulate and then convert it again in again in a string.

Comment: This works - you have a small mistake in the JS, you haven't escaped the "/" in the closing tag but otherwise it works. I upvoted it but will wait before marking the accepted answer when I find out why my attempts didn't work - what is the reason for the jQuery object filtering to fail?

Comment: Thanks, regex edited :) See Darhazer answer, he explains why it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Both `not` filters will search only on the first level, and not down the tree, they filter collections and do not process the DOM tree recursively.

Assuming that myHtmlString IS a jQuery object (so it's valid **context**)

`$(':not(a)', myHtmlString);`

will return **collection** of the 2 DOM nodes, contained in the `myHhtmlString`, as neither of them is an 'a' element

`$(myHtmlString).not('a');`

will also return a collection, but with the original HTML, as it's the only element provided and it's not an 'a' element. The difference between the 2 versions is the **context** provided in the first line of code, so it filter's the children elements of myHtmlString. If you change `div.venue-tooltip` to `a.venue-tooltip`, you will see it filtered in the first version.

Answer (score 1):

This would work, although it's long winded and I have doubts about it's efficiency-

```
var h = '<div><div class="venue-tooltip">Filling station<div><a class="manage-venue-details" rel="venue-id-10" href="javascript:void(0);">Add filling station info</a></div></div></div>';
$(h).find("a").each(function () {
  //need to get full outer html for replace to work  
  h = h.replace($(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html(),'')  
})
alert(h);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/XBjNS/

Comment: Desn't seem efficient, but nice one, you do know how to play with jQuery! Any idea why trying to filter through jQuery object loaded with html string does not work? This is what I strive to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $.strRemove = function(theTarget, theString) {
        return $("<div/>").append(
            $(theTarget, theString).remove().end()
        ).html();
    };
})(jQuery);

var htmlToBeChanged=$("#123").html();

var changedHtml= $.strRemove("a",htmlToBeChanged)
console.log(changedHtml);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kpNr/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(myHtmlString).find('a').remove();
$(myHtmlString).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: That doesn't actually change the contents of `myHtmlString`, so calling `$()` on `myHtmlString` again just returns the same DOM with the `a` element still there.

Comment: Did you test your answer? It simply doesn't work, first you probably wanted to do $(myHtmlString).remove('a'); but both cases do not work on HTML loaded from string.

Comment: It would work if written as myHtmlString = $(myHtmlString); myHtmlString.find('a').remove(); myHtmlString = myHtmlString.html();